# Posting data from phpMyAdmin to IOS app.

Tags: ios, phpmyadmin

I have seen a lot of tutorials how to connect IOS application with external database but none of them doesn't really show how to read data from phpMyAdmin. My idea is to read data from phpMyAdmin and show it in UITableView. Can someone show me some tutorial how to make my idea happen, i would really appreciate that.

Comment: I found that but it didn't help me..

Comment: I think you might need to learn some `PHP` or another server side language in order to write a basic web service for this. It's not a simple one liner.

Comment: I Know web development i am just asking about IOS. Maybe i can somehow connect IOS to PHP.?

Comment: So write a php script on your server that gets your data from the database, and then use an `NSMutableURLRequest` to run that script and retrieve the information. [Like This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13402155/757214)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use a NSURLConnection (iOS7+: NSURLSession) to get the output of your service running on the server:

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com/path/to/service.php";

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10000];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSError *error;

    if (data) {
       // process the data...
    }


}];
```

another great tutorial: http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/